# How to get the email's content (Email body and attachements) from the spring Integration message?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, jakarta-mail

So I integrated Spring Integration in order to receive mails and everything works fine.

I have trying converting the payload which is a byte array into a string. The output was divided into unprocessed sections.

```
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel="emailChannel")
public void handleMessage(Message message, @Header("campaign_id") String campaign_id, @Header("tenant_identifier") String tenant_identifier) {
    try {
        TenantContext.setTenantId(tenant_identifier);

        emailCampaignService.recieveMailMessage(message, campaign_id);
    } catch (Exception e) {
       log.error("RecieveMailException{0}", e.getMessage());
    }finally {
        TenantContext.clearTenantId();
    }
    System.out.println(" campaign_id: " + campaign_id );
}
```

I'm trying to access the emails content and attachments with no success. I believe it's something to do with the message payload.

Now the ImapAdapter is as follows :

private IntegrationFlow createImapAdapter (String protocol, String host, Integer port, String inboxFolder, String username, String password, Long campaignId,String tenantIdenifier) {
        IntegrationFlow flow = IntegrationFlows
                .from(Mail.imapInboundAdapter(imapUrl(protocol,host, port, inboxFolder, username, password))
                        .javaMailProperties(p -> p.put("mail.debug", "false"))
                        .searchTermStrategy((supportedFlags, folder) -> {
                            Flags flags = new Flags(Flags.Flag.SEEN);
                            return new FlagTerm(flags, false);
                        })
                        .userFlag("CLC") // needed by the SI test server - not needed if server supports /SEEN
                        .headerMapper(new DefaultMailHeaderMapper()), e -> e.autoStartup(true)
                        .poller(p -> p.fixedDelay(1000)))
                    .enrichHeaders(s ->  {
                        s.header("campaign_id",new StaticHeaderValueMessageProcessor(campaignId.toString()));
                        s.header("tenant_identifier",new StaticHeaderValueMessageProcessor(tenantIdenifier));
                    })
                .channel("emailChannel")
                .get();

```
    return flow;
}
```

and the message content comes in this format (example) :

--000000000000f8ac18058cc6e3b0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"

this is the content I want to get

--000000000000f8ac18058cc6e3b0
Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8"

this is the content I want to get

--000000000000f8ac18058cc6e3b0--

Comment: Looks like `emailCampaignService.recieveMailMessage()` is your own code. We definitely don't know what's going on there. Plus you haven't shared with us what's the problem you're having.

Comment: Start with the [JavaMail FAQ](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ) and [JavaMail APIs](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/) to find lots of examples for how to process the Message object to read the content of a message.